# Adding a date picker to my html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datepicker

I am trying to add a date picker to my nav bar... the text box pops up but the datepicker does not pop up. Please help me fix the date picker.
 html code :

```
    <li><a herf='#'>Country</a>

                    <ul>
                        <li><a herf= "#">Brazil</a></li>
                        <li><a herf= "#">Taiwan</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </li>
                <li><a herf="#payperiod">Pay Period</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a herf= "#">Start Date <input type='date' id="beginning"></a>
                         <script>
                          $(function() {
                            $('#beginning').datepicker();
                          });
                         </script></li> 

                         <li><a herf= "#">End Date <input type='date' id='ending'></a>
                         <script>
                          $(function() {
                            $('#ending').datepicker();
                          });
                         </script></li> 




                     </ul>
```

this is the js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#beginning").datepicker();
$("#ending").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: any error in your browser console... did you include jquery-ui.js/css files

Comment: beginning id is duplicate

Comment: Which extension are you using ? JQuery UI, Bootstrap Datepicker/datetimepicker ? Else ?

Comment: `input` is invalid child of `<a>` and `herf` should be `href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
<input type="text" id="beginning">
```

use

```
<input type="date" id="beginning">
```

This will tell the browsers to parse that input as date, thus display the date picker.

Comment: tel us more about this? how to set current date to it.